# Breaking a foreach loop after two iterations

Tags: php, foreach

How can I brake a foreach loop after two iterations, something like this:

```
foreach($posttags as $tags){     
  $tag1 = $tags->slug;  
} --- this is the first iteration, stored in the variable $tag1

foreach($posttags as $tags){     
  $tag2 = $tags->slug;  
} ---- this is the second iteration, stored in the variable $tag2

brake; --- brake the foreach loop
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Couldn't you set both at the same time?

Comment: break may not brake code, but brake will most assuredly not break as expected.

Comment: `break` *after* a `foreach`? What is it supposed to break? Also, two *loops* is not the same as two *iterations* in one loop.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588892/can-you-exit-a-loop-in-php

Comment: I see I have failed explaining, the code follow a logic

Comment: As written the code will assign the `slug` property of the last element of the `$posttags` array to both `$tag1` and `$tag2`. And then it might produce a warning or error about `break` appearing outside the context of a loop/case. Explain the logic in words or provide an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious answer is not to use a foreach loop if you don't want to loop through each item.  Use some other looping structure, or grab the first and second items manually if that's what you really want.