# How to display limited number of tags post?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a post with tags:b1,b2,b3. But in the category template, I want to show only 2 tags for the post:b1,b2. How can I do it ?
Now I use the following code to display tags of the post:

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        echo '<li>' .$tag->name. '</li>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

What I want to:

[image]

Comment: It depends.  Are you filtering out b3 because it is the last tag? or because you have a tag limit of 2? or because of b3's actual tag value? or something else?

Comment: I need to display only 2 of the tag. Limited to 2 @mickmackusa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: Going back to foreach() with a break in it.

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if($posttags){
    foreach($posttags as $index=>$tag){
        echo '<li>' .$tag->name. '</li>'; // echos while $index == 0 & 1
        if($index>0){break;}  // second iteration ($index==1) breaks the loop
    }
}
?>
```

Or if the $posttags array does not use numerical keys, you create your own iteration counter:

```
if($posttags){
    $x=0;
    foreach($posttags as $tag){
        echo '<li>' .$tag->name. '</li>'; 
        if(++$x==2){break;}  // increment and test $x (first $x=1, second $x=2 so break)
    }
}
```

Comment: Too easy, mate!

Comment: Hello! There was a problem when we have only one tag, an error @mickmackusa

Comment: @RomanVerner I've updated it.  Declaring a key/index in the foreach loop allows an iteration-dependent break.  Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215588/break-out-of-if-and-foreach

Comment: More duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059579/breaking-a-foreach-loop-after-two-iterations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865373/how-would-i-stop-this-foreach-loop-after-3-iterations

Answer (score 0):

This tags only used in wordpress theme in html format. To display 2 tags.
If you want to display 4 tags change these code

> ++$x==4

```
         <?php $tags = get_tags(); ?>
          <?php if($tags){ ?>
            <?php $x=0; ?>
          <?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ) { ?>
              <a class="badge bg-primary bg-opacity-10 text-primary" href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ); ?> " rel="tag"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></a>
              <?php if(++$x==2){break;} ?>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
```