# How to conditionally stop a loop?

Tags: php, loops

Here is the code :

```
<tbody id=cobrancas-tbody><?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($cliente->cobrancas); $i++) : ?>
    <?php if ($cliente->cobrancas[$i]->valorpago > 0) continue ?>
        <tr class="<?php echo interpretar_cobranca($cliente->cobrancas[$i]) ?>"> 
            <td class=acoes>
                <form action=# method=post>
                    <input type=hidden name=index value=<?php echo $i ?> />
                </form>
                <?php echo $cliente->cobrancas[$i]->nossonumero ?>
                <a href=# class=boleto title="Imprimir segunda via"><img src=http://findicons.com/files/icons/753/gnome_desktop/64/gnome_printer.png     height="32"                 width="32"></a>
            </td>
```

How can i Stop the Print to Break and not Continue?

Comment: $i = count($cliente->cobrancas) ?

Comment: Use `break;` instead of `continue;` ?

Comment: yes, it print, 3 values after "continue" ...  i want to print only one ..and stop

Comment: Use break similar maybe  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588892/can-you-exit-a-loop-in-php

Answer (score 0):

just use `break`:

```
<?php if ($cliente->cobrancas[$i]->valorpago > 0){
    echo $cliente->cobrancas[$i]->valorpago;
    break;
}?>
```

*edited according to OP's comments.*

Comment: yes, it's `break` not `return` in PHP, thanks Muhammad!

Comment: blank result, no print' s.   it print, 3 values after "continue" ... i want to print only one ..and stop

Comment: @JJuniorCarneiro then do this now that you know how to break out a `for` loop?

Comment: @JJuniorCarneiro and I don't understand what you try to achieve, sorry.

Comment: @low_rents first ***print*** the value and then break, otherwise nothing will ever get printed. Not even the first one

Comment: @JJuniorCarneiro move the break statement after the print statement

Comment: @JJuniorCarneiro i just edited my answer - try it. and pls update your question so that it contains your whole code - you have been mentioning "print" a couple of times, but there is nor "print" in your code.

Comment: yes no print,,   i just want to show only one value

Comment: @JJuniorCarneiro but to show it you'll have to print it - or output it in another way?

Comment: i edit the code up the page ....    look there,, it shows me 3 values after,,,but i just want one

Comment: the code of    
low_rents. works ,,, but just showing the next number , and hiding the content of the rule code