# php foreach with if loop through array of objects performing if condition times members in array instead of only once

Tags: php

`$_SESSION['quantity']` is an array of Objects.

let's say I already added a product with `id = 1` to the array.

Next I add same product with `id = 1` , so now `$sameProduct = 1` and is set.

`$q->update()` increments by the property 'quantity' of that object by 1.

The code works well when there is only one item in the array, the problem starts when there are more than one item. The code runs times there items in the array instead of only once for that particular object.

```
   <?php 
if(!session_start()){session_start();}

require_once 'components/sql_login.php';
require_once 'components/header.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']) != ""){
    echo "<script> window.location.href = 'user/cart.php'; </script>";
    }

if(!isset($_SESSION['productIds'])){$_SESSION['productIds']=array();}
if(!isset($_SESSION['cartProducts'])){$_SESSION['cartProducts']=array();}
if(!isset($_SESSION['quantity'])){$_SESSION['quantity']=array();}

if (isset($_GET['f'])){ 
    if(!in_array($_GET['f'],$_SESSION['productIds'])){
    $newFairy = $_GET['f'];
    array_push($_SESSION['productIds'],$newFairy);

        } else {$oldFairy = $_GET['f'];}
    }


    foreach($_SESSION['productIds'] as $newItem){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?";
    if($getFairy = $sqlConnection->prepare($query)){
        $getFairy->bind_param("i",$newItem);
        $getFairy->execute();
        $result = $getFairy->get_result();
        $row    = $result->fetch_array();
        $getFairy->close();

            $newProduct = new AddProduct($row);
            }

    if (!in_array($newProduct,$_SESSION['cartProducts'])){

        array_push($_SESSION['cartProducts'],$newProduct);
        $quantity   = new quantityUpdate($newProduct);
        array_push($_SESSION['quantity'],$quantity);
            print_r($_SESSION['quantity']);
                } else {

                        if(isset($oldFairy) != ""){
                        $founded = false;
                    foreach($_SESSION['quantity'] as $q){

                    if($q->id == $oldFairy && $founded != true){        
                        $q->update();
                        $founded = true;

                    print_r($_SESSION['quantity']);
                    echo "<br>count: ".count($_SESSION['quantity'])."<br>";

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


if($_SESSION['productIds'] != ""){

    $c = count($_SESSION['cartProducts']);


        if($c == 0){
        $outPutProduct = "<h3>כרגע אין מוצרים בעגלת הקניות</h3>";

        echo "<br>cartProducts: ".$c;
        echo "<br>productIds: ".count($_SESSION['productIds']);
        } else if ($c == 1){
        $outPutProduct = $_SESSION['cartProducts'][0]->output;

        echo "<br>cartProducts: ".$c;
        echo "<br>productIds: ".count($_SESSION['productIds']);
        } else {                

                $outPutProduct = $_SESSION['cartProducts'][0]->output;
            for($x=1; $x<count($_SESSION['cartProducts']);$x++){
                $outPutProduct .= "<hr>".$_SESSION['cartProducts'][$x]->output;

                }
                echo "<br>cartProducts: ".$c;
                echo "<br>productIds: ".count($_SESSION['productIds']);
        }

    } 

Class quantityUpdate{

    var $id;
    var $quantity = 1;

    function __construct($obj){
        $this->id = $obj->id;
        }

    function update(){
        $this->quantity += 1;
        }
    }   

Class AddProduct{

    var $image;
    var $name;
    var $selectQnty;
    var $desc;
    var $id;
    var $price;
    var $output;

    function __construct($fairy){
        $this->image        = $fairy['img'];
        $this->name         = $fairy['name'];
        $this->desc         = $fairy['description'];
        $this->id           = $fairy['id'];
        $this->price        = $fairy['price'];
        $this->selectQnty   = "<select id='quantity".$this->id."'>" 
                            ."<option id='1' value='1'>1</option>"
                            ."<option id='2' value='2'>2</option>"
                            ."<option id='3' value='3'>3</option>"
                            ."<option id='4' value='4'>4</option>"
                            ."<option id='5' value='5'>5</option>"
                            ."<option id='6' value='6'>6</option>"
                            ."<option id='7' value='7'>7</option>"
                            ."<option id='8' value='8'>8</option>"
                            ."<option id='9' value='9'>9</option>"
                            ."<option id='10' value='10'>10</option>"
                            ."</select>"
                            ."<span class='qnty'>x</span>";

        $this->output       = $this->image.$this->selectQnty
                            ."<span id='name' class='name'>".$this->name."</span>"
                            ."<span id='desc' class='desc'>".$this->desc."</span>"
                            ."<span id='id' class='id'>מק״ט: 000".$this->id."</span>"
                            ."<span id='price' class='price'>".$this->price."₪</span>"
                            ."<button onclick='removeItem(".$this->id.")' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></button>";

        }   
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please try to provide a *minimal* code example of non-working code in the future, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve This basically boils down to a problem with one of your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"break 2;" did it!
the code:

```
    if(isset($existingProduct) != ""){
                foreach($_SESSION['quantity'] as $q){
                    if($existingProduct == $q->id){     
                    $q->update();
                    print_r($_SESSION['quantity']);
                    break 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

post answer #103:

"
As stated in other posts, you can use the break keyword. One thing that was hinted at but not explained is that the keyword can take a numeric value to tell PHP how many levels to break from.

For example, if you have three foreach loops nested in each other trying to find a piece of information, you could do 'break 3' to get out of all three nested loops. This will work for the 'for', 'foreach', 'while', 'do-while', or 'switch' structures.

Source: [Can you 'exit' a loop in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588892/can-you-exit-a-loop-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

try to put a break, and only do once whn firs concurrence:

```
$founded = false;
    foreach($_SESSION['quantity'] as $q){
    if($q->id == $sameProduct && !$founded){     
    $q->update();
$founded=true;
    return $founded;
        }
    }
```

Putting a semaphore, could be done, and try to look with a return stops the foreach

Comment: putting a break did not help me :( it does the same, looping twice(when 2 items in array).

Comment: tried with $founded, no change. 
but when putting "return $founded", it works, it increments only once, but my whole page disappeared

Answer (score 0):

is it for you possible to use the id of your product as array key?

Like :

```
$_SESSION['quantity'][$sameProduct]
```

In this case you dont need to loop $_SESSION['quantity']

Comment: thanks, but it did not work...

    if(isset($oldFairy) != ""){
     
         if(array_key_exists($oldFairy,$_SESSION['quantity'])){  
      $_SESSION['quantity'][$oldFairy]->update();
     print_r($_SESSION['quantity']);
     echo "<br>count: ".count($_SESSION['quantity'])."     <br>";
      }
     }