# PHP making a loop end if variable in the loop don't exist

Tags: php, loops

I can't figure out a solution for this so I'm asking here if someone can help me figure this out!

This is how I make loops now when I need a increasing number somewhere in the code. So I tell before how many times i want the loop to run, so in this example 1000 times.

```
$itemsqueue = 1000;
for ($qu = 1 ; $qu <= $itemsqueue; $qu++){

}
```

But sometimes I don't know how many lines the "csv" database is, it might be 10,000 lines or 5 lines. So then I would like to have something that makes the loop stop if something in the the actual loop is empty or not set.

Of course the example code below don't work, but this is kind of what I'm thinking I need.

```
if (empty($queue[$qu][1]) ){
  for ($qu = 1 ; $qu++){
  }
}
```

Hopefully I made some sense.

Comment: Have a look at `foreach()` loops, or if reading a csv , have a look at other example code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php

Comment: Convert csv data into array & then use count() for condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you 'exit' a loop in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588892/can-you-exit-a-loop-in-php)

Comment: Was hoping for a quick fix :) I guess your right its best to rewrite how i fetch the actual csv. As this is feach within the data that is already fetched from the actual csv data. Thanks Michel, again!

Comment: Well, a quickfix could be checking if the current value you would be trying to use is *set* or *not*, and then **break** the loop. But that's extra work that's unnecessary when using `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ash for getting me in the right direction.
I added this to the code that reads the csv firstly!

```
$queuecount = count($data);
```

And now i know how many lines each CSV is!

So now i can just add that on the item queue!

```
for ($qu = 1 ; $qu <= $queuecount; $qu++){
}
```

Sweet!